# How can I bin a Pandas Series setting the bin size to a preset value of max/min for each bin

Tags: python, pandas, series, binning

I have a pd.Series of floats and I would like to bin it into **n bins** where the bin size for each bin is set so that max/min is a preset value (e.g. 1.20)?

The requirement means that the size of the bins is not constant. For example:

```
data = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 11.0))
print(data)

0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     4.0
4     5.0
5     6.0
6     7.0
7     8.0
8     9.0
9    10.0
dtype: float64
```

I would like the bin sizes to be:

```
1.00 <= bin 1 < 1.20
1.20 <= bin 2 < 1.20 x 1.20 = 1.44
1.44 <= bin 3 < 1.44 x 1.20 = 1.73
...
```

etc

Thanks

Comment: `bins = [1.20**i for i in range(0,10)]; pd.cuts(data, bins=bins)`?

Comment: How is the numbers of bins determined?

Comment: The number of bins is flexible. It depends on the overall max/min ratio

Comment: I believe there is a small typo in Quang Hoang's answer. It should read: pd.cut() (not pd.cuts()). Otherwise it works just fine, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all the suggestions. None does quite what I was after (probably because my original question wasn't clear enough) but they really helped me figure out what to do so I have decided to post my own answer (I hope this is what I am supposed to do as I am relatively new at being an active member of stackoverflow...)

I liked @yatu's vectorised suggestion best because it will scale better with large data sets but I am after the means to not only automatically calculate the bins but also figure out the minimum number of bins needed to cover the data set.

This is my proposed algorithm:

1. The bin size is defined so that bin_max_i/bin_min_i is constant:

```
bin_max_i / bin_min_i = bin_ratio
```

2. Figure out the number of bins for the required bin size (bin_ratio):

```
data_ratio = data_max / data_min
n_bins = math.ceil( math.log(data_ratio) / math.log(bin_ratio) )
```

3. Set the lower boundary for the smallest bin so that the smallest data point fits in it:

```
bin_min_0 = data_min
```

4. Create n non-overlapping bins meeting the conditions:

```
bin_min_i+1 = bin_max_i
bin_max_i+1 = bin_min_i+1 * bin_ratio
```

5. Stop creating further bins once all dataset can be split between the bins already created. In other words, stop once:

```
bin_max_last > data_max
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
import math
import pandas as pd

bin_ratio = 1.20

data = pd.Series(np.arange(2,12))
data_ratio = max(data) / min(data)

n_bins = math.ceil( math.log(data_ratio) / math.log(bin_ratio) )
n_bins = n_bins + 1               # bin ranges are defined as [min, max)

bins = np.full(n_bins, bin_ratio) # initialise the ratios for the bins limits
bins[0] = bin_min_0               # initialise the lower limit for the 1st bin
bins = np.cumprod(bins)           # generate bins

print(bins)
[ 2.          2.4         2.88        3.456       4.1472      4.97664
  5.971968    7.1663616   8.59963392 10.3195607  12.38347284]
```

I am now set to build a histogram of the data:

```
data.hist(bins=bins)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), where the `bins` can be computed taking the [`np.cumprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) of an array filled with `1.2`:

```
data = pd.Series(list(range(11)))
import numpy as np

n = 20 # set accordingly
bins= np.r_[0,np.cumprod(np.full(n, 1.2))]
# array([ 0.        ,  1.2       ,  1.44      ,  1.728 ...
pd.cut(data, bins)

0                 NaN
1          (0.0, 1.2]
2      (1.728, 2.074]
3      (2.986, 3.583]
4        (3.583, 4.3]
5         (4.3, 5.16]
6       (5.16, 6.192]
7       (6.192, 7.43]
8       (7.43, 8.916]
9     (8.916, 10.699]
10    (8.916, 10.699]
dtype: category
```

---

Where bins in this case goes up to:

```
np.r_[0,np.cumprod(np.full(20, 1.2))]

array([ 0.        ,  1.2       ,  1.44      ,  1.728     ,  2.0736    ,
        2.48832   ,  2.985984  ,  3.5831808 ,  4.29981696,  5.15978035,
        6.19173642,  7.43008371,  8.91610045, 10.69932054, 12.83918465,
       15.40702157, 18.48842589, 22.18611107, 26.62333328, 31.94799994,
       38.33759992])
```

So you'll have to set that according to the range of values of the actual data

Comment: What is the purpose of `np.r_()` ? It also works with `pd.Series(np.cumprod(np.full(20, 1.2)))`. Thanks

Comment: Just adding the lower boundary `(0,1.2]` @user13578

Answer (score 0):

This is I believe the best way to do it because you are considering the `max` and `min` values from your array. Therefore you won't need to worry about what values are you using, only the **multiplier** or step_size for your bins (of course you'd need to add a column name or some additional information if you will be working with a DataFrame):

```
data = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 11.0))
bins = []
i = min(data)
while i < max(data):
    bins.append(i)
    i = i*1.2
    bins.append(i)
bins = list(set(bins))
bins.sort()
df = pd.cut(data,bins,include_lowest=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0       (0.999, 1.2]
1     (1.728, 2.074]
2     (2.986, 3.583]
3       (3.583, 4.3]
4        (4.3, 5.16]
5      (5.16, 6.192]
6      (6.192, 7.43]
7      (7.43, 8.916]
8    (8.916, 10.699]
9    (8.916, 10.699]
```

Bins output:

```
Categories (13, interval[float64]): [(0.999, 1.2] < (1.2, 1.44] < (1.44, 1.728] < (1.728, 2.074] < ... <
                                     (5.16, 6.192] < (6.192, 7.43] < (7.43, 8.916] <
                                     (8.916, 10.699]]
```